# Windows 7 permissions problem

Tags: windows-7

I downloaded SQL Server Migration Assistant 2008 for MySQL. These are two executable files. Whenever I try to execute any file, it displays this error:

[image]

I right-clicked on the file and check the file's security settings. I took the ownership as an administrator, added special permissions and whatever I could, but it is still not opening.

I run it as an administrator also, but still it is giving this error.

Windows 7 is installed on G partition of my hard drive.

Comment: are you on a domain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are administrator, Windows 7 runs all programs with degraded permissions. So try right-clicking the .msi file and executing it using "Run as administrator".

If this doesn't work, turn off UAC and try again.

Lastly, check the permissions on `C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe` itself. If they are wrong, then your computer might be infected. Run several checks by several antivirus products and then use `sfc /scannow` as explained [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html).

It seems that you have a multi-boot of XP and 7. It also seems that you have installed 7 to the C disk, although its Windows folder is on G (since otherwise when booting under 7, G would have been called C, as the boot drive is always C). It is then possible that while booted under XP, you have changed files or permissions on G. As user accounts under XP are not identical to 7, this would cause a serious problem that can only be fixed by a [Repair Install](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

Comment: In C: I have Windows XP installed.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and filter the Result column on `ACCESS DENIED`.

Answer (score 1):

As with Creedorofl, this is probably because you're trying to run it from inside your Windows\System32 directory. Is this where the installer is extracting the files to, or did you put the files there and try to run them?

Comment: I downloaded the files to other partition and executing them from there.

Comment: So where the files indeed trying to be executed from the system32 directory?

Comment: The file that I downloaded is attempting to execute a file: MsiExec that resides in the System32 folder. I also changed the ownership, but still not working.

Comment: msi files should be default extract to the %userprofile%\Local Settings\Temp\... directory. I'm not sure what's going on in your case, if this is a by design behavior that shows a problem in your system config, or if there is something wrong in how paths are set up on your system. Try extracting the msi file using the following syntax:

msiexec /a PathToMSIFile /qb TARGETDIR=DirectoryToExtractTo

And then run the package installer from the already extracted files.

Comment: @music2myear: Did what you suggested, still not working.

Comment: Right click on the extracted msi installer and select run as administrator.

Comment: @Moab Did the same, still not working.

Comment: Then it's a problem with the installer or your computer. Hope it's the installer, because that's easy to get a clean copy of.

Comment: @Rohit, you changed owner of the "msiexec.exe file?, but did you change permissions for the new owner you assigned?

Answer (score 1):

Try the installing the application by enabling the default admin account .
Follow these steps to enable Admin access:

**Use the Local Users and Groups MMC console**
Change the properties of the Administrator account by using the Local Users and Groups Microsoft Management Console (MMC).

```
Open the MMC console and select Local Users and Groups.

Right-click the Administrator account and select Properties.

The Administrator Properties window appears.

On the General tab, clear the Account is Disabled check box.

Close the MMC console.
```

Find more info about enabling admin account [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744293%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this means it's trying to read or install to a specific folder you don't have access to. So that folder is what you need to take ownership of. Unfortunately I'm not sure of a way to figure out which one.

One option is to run a command prompt as administrator, then do msiexec /a G:\whatever.msi . This may be better for giving your installation admin. priveleves. You can also unzip MSI files with a utility called lessmsierables... http://www.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php?p=33498&t=4&i=1 . Maybe there's a sub-installer you can work from once it's unzipped.